# Has the Olympic host nation ever been changed after it was announced

Tags: history, olympics

The stability of Brazil makes me wonder what will happen in 2016 if Brazil is not in a position to play host to the games.  Has this ever happened before?  Are there contingency plans for such an event?

Comment: Sydney was briefly stripped of its hosting of the 2000 Olympics. The then premier of NSW, Bob Carr, talked about it on radio. It happened 12 years and [3 days ago](http://www.abc.net.au/triplej/30years/stories/s1305229.htm), to be precise.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The 1976 Olympics are probably the closest example available. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1976_Winter_Olympics), Denver was originally scheduled to host the 1976 Winter Olympics:

> The games were originally awarded to Denver in May 12, 1970, but a 300
> percent rise in costs and worries about environmental impact led to
> Colorado voters' rejection on November 7, 1972, by a 3 to 2 margin, of
> a $5 million bond issue to finance the games with public funds.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1940_Summer_Olympics)
>
> Denver officially withdrew on November 15, and the IOC then offered
> the games to Whistler, British Columbia, Canada, but they too declined
> owing to a change of government following elections. Whistler would go
> on to be associated with neighbouring Vancouver's successful bid for
> the 2010 games.
>
> Salt Lake City, Utah, which would eventually host in 2002, offered
> itself as a potential host after the withdrawal of Denver. The IOC,
> still reeling from the Denver rejection, declined and **selected
> Innsbruck, which had hosted the 1964 Winter Olympics games** twelve
> years earlier, on February 5, 1973.

Notably, per Wikipedia ([Summer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1940_Summer_Olympics) and [Winter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1940_Winter_Olympics), the host sites for the 1940 Games were also to be replaced, had the Olympics not been canceled due to the onset of World War II:

> The anticipated 1940 Summer Olympics, officially known as the Games of
> the XII Olympiad and originally scheduled to be held from September 21
> to October 6, 1940, in Tokyo, Japan, were cancelled due to the
> outbreak of World War II. Tokyo was stripped of its host status for
> the Games by the IOC after the renunciation by the Japanese of the
> IOC's Cairo Conference of 1938, due to the outbreak of the Second
> Sino-Japanese War. The government of Japan had abandoned its support
> for the 1940 Games in July 1938. The IOC then awarded the Games to
> Helsinki, Finland, the runner-up in the original bidding process. The
> Games were then scheduled to be staged from July 20 to August 4, 1940.
> The Olympic Games were suspended indefinitely following the outbreak
> of World War II and did not resume until the London Games of 1948.

and

> The games were cancelled due to the onset of World War II. Sapporo was
> selected to be the host of the fifth edition Winter Olympics scheduled
> February 3-12, 1940, but Japan gave the Games back to the IOC in July
> 1938, after the outbreak of the Second Sino-Japanese War in 1937.
> Sapporo subsequently hosted the 1972 Winter Olympics.
>
> The IOC then
> decided to give the Winter Olympics to St Moritz, Switzerland, which
> had hosted in 1928. Due to controversies between the Swiss organizing
> team and the IOC, the Games were withdrawn again.
>
> In the spring of
> 1939, the IOC gave the 1940 Winter Olympics, now scheduled for
> February 2-11, to Garmisch-Partenkirchen, Germany, where the previous
> 1936 games had been held. Three months later Germany invaded Poland on
> September 1 to ignite World War II, and the Winter Games were
> cancelled in November. Likewise, the 1944 games, awarded in 1939 to
> Cortina d'Ampezzo, Italy, were cancelled in 1941.

The IOC would select an alternate host site, probably at a site that had hosted recently to ensure that the requisite facilities would be in place. Innsbruck had hosted the 1964 Games, and were thus chosen as the alternate host.